# inserting big json file into mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am working on flask and mongodb. I am new to mongodb, I realized that mongodb do not let me  insert json file to database, the file size is greater than 16mb

Is there  any other database that is similar to mongodb (JSON object based) ?

Thank You

Comment: You can explore couchdb: http://couchdb.apache.org/

Comment: @YamanJain I looked at the documentation for CouchDB, I diot get how to save and retrieve daata. In my case i want to save a python dictionary so that i can retrive by key.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of PostgreSQL also for json kind of data to store, based on your Application requirements.

Please refer their official documentation for more information.

Hope the below links can be useful.

1.[Postgre Data Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html)

2.[Postgre SQL and Json](http://clarkdave.net/2013/06/what-can-you-do-with-postgresql-and-json/)